# An exercise in model theory about positive homomorphisms

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

> A formula is called *positive* if is is built from atomic formulas
>   using only $\land, \lor, \exists$ and $\forall$. A homomorphism $f : M \to N$
>   is *positive* if $$ M \models \varphi(m_1, \cdots, m_n) \Rightarrow N \models \varphi(f(m_1), \cdots, f(m_n)) $$
>   for all positive $\varphi(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ and all $m_1, \cdots, m_n \in M$.
>   Let $T$ be a satisfiable $L$-theory and $$ T_0 = \{\varphi : \varphi \text{ is positive and } T \models \varphi \} \, . $$
>
> Prove that for any model $A \models T_0$ there is a model $C$ such
>   that there exists 1) a model $B \models T$ and a positive homomorphism
>   $g : B \to C$; and 2)  an elementary embedding $h : A \to C$ with
>   $\text{Im}(h) \subset \text{Im}(g)$. [Where $\text{Im}(\cdot)$ stands
>   for "image"]

I really don't know how to approach such a problem. The best I can think of is to prove that there is a model for $\text{ElDiag}(A) \cup \{\varphi : B \models \varphi \text{ and } \varphi \text{ is positive}\}$ for some model $B \models T$ to which we have added all the constants of $L_A$ ($L_A$ is $L$ with all the elements in $A$ added as constants; $\text{ElDiag}$ = elementary diagram). Maybe we can use compactness to prove the existence, utilising that we know $A \models T_0$ and we have freedom to choose $B \models T$?

Could you provide a hint? I have been at this exercise for several days, but am completely stuck; I have no strategy to approach it.

Comment: What are the $>\to$ and $>\Rightarrow$ supposed to mean? And the $>$ in the definition of $T_0$?

Comment: @tomasz Nothing. I fixed it now; apparently the blockquote tool does not handle LaTeX well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea to solve the problem by the method of diagrams and compactness is the right one. But the first thing you should ask yourself is: What is $B$, and what is its relationship to $A$? Can we take *any* model $B\models T$?

Well, no, we can't in general... Since we must have $\text{Im}(h)\subseteq \text{Im}(g)$, for all $a\in A$ there must be some $a'\in B$ such that it is consistent that $g(a') = h(a)$, where $h$ is some elementary embedding $A\to C$ and $g$ is some positive homomorphism $B\to C$. What does this consistency amount to? Suppose $\varphi(x)$ is a positive formula such that $B\models \varphi(a')$, where $h(a) = g(a')$. Then $C\models \varphi(g(a'))$, so $C\models \varphi(h(a))$, and $A\models \varphi(a)$. This is a constraint on $B$: If $A\models \lnot \varphi(a)$, then we must have $B\models \lnot \varphi(a')$.

So let's define a *negative* formula to be the negation of a positive formula, and consider the $L_A$-theory: $$T\cup \text{Diag}^-(A)\text{, where }\text{Diag}^-(A) = \{\psi(a)\mid \psi(x)\text{ is negative, and }A\models \psi(a)\}.$$

You can show by compactness that this theory is consistent, using our assumption that $A\models T_0$.

So $B$ be a model. $B$ is an $L_A$-structure, so when we form the language $L_B$, we reuse the constants naming the elements of $A$, i.e. $L_A\subseteq L_B$. Now consider the $L_B$-theory: $$\text{ElDiag}(A)\cup \text{Diag}^+(B)\text{, where }\text{Diag}^+(B) = \{\varphi(b)\mid \varphi(x)\text{ is positive, and }B\models \psi(b)\}.$$

It remains to show that this theory is consistent, using compactness and the fact that $B\models \text{Diag}^-(A)$.

Comment: Thank-you, Alex. I knew I was not that far off. This was a very good tip. I have found the solution now, but it was still not quite trivial to me (especially how to deal with the constants). You left me enough work to learn something :) . Can I interpret your second paragraph as to how you (or someone in general) might have come to this solution?

Comment: @Joachim Yes, I had to think through the reasoning in the second paragraph to see which theory to write down when finding $B$.